# Luma theme has high CLS. Any suggestions to fix it?

Tags: magento2, optimization

So, trying to find ways to lower my CLS I figured to run a demo Luma site to determine a baseline.

Well, that is one bad baseline with a CLS of 0.2 or 0.4, depending how pagespeed interprets the website. Its about the product pages in particular. It seems the product images are loaded after the title (which is below the image) thus pushing the title down creating a CLS.

You can check it out here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmagento2demo.firemultimedia.nl%2Fbreathe-easy-tank.html

Anyway, does anybody has a solution and/or opinion of the severity of such an issue?

I cant find anything on google about this, and I cant find any modules or fixes for this. Did anybody encountered the same issue?

Cheers,